# Query from results of SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Not sure how to ask this question, so I ask by giving scenario.

```
Select ID, CompanyID, Company_name from memberdetails where status in ('A','S');
```

the query returns say 1000 rows. Now I want to search the table `industry_catagory` with the result under column `CompanyID` from above. How can I create this is one single `sql` statement.

Comment: Do you need the results from the first query as well? Or do you just need the `CompanyID` so you can use it for the second query?

Comment: `Join` to the two tables together on CompanyId.

Comment: You could join or use a subquery. Use the query provided as a subquery WHERE companyID IN ( Select ID, CompanyID, Company_name from memberdetails where status in ('A','S'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the next approaches:

**Sub-Query:-**

```
Select CompanyID from industry_catagory 
where CompanyID in (Select CompanyID from memberdetails where status in ('A','S'))
```

**Join:-**

```
Select CompanyID 
from industry_catagory a , memberdetails b
where a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID
and b.status in ('A','S')
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 2):

This should be using and more up to date Join syntax:

```
SELECT CompanyID 
FROM industry_catagory a 
INNER JOIN memberdetails b ON a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID
WHERE b.status in ('A','S')
```